# Generate column chart from updated results

Tags: excel, charts, commandbutton, column-chart, vba

The following code, find the appropriate row based on today's date (the date is already written manually in column A) and insert the data on the same row. I need to add the last result( today's date )to a column chart on a different sheet called "charts".

```
Sub Worksheets_Summary()
Dim OldSheet As Worksheet
Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim RwNum As Long
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = ThisWorkbook
Set NewSheet = book.Worksheets("Summary")
RwNum = NewSheet.Columns(1).Find(Date).Row
ColNum = 1
For Each OldSheet In book.Worksheets
    If OldSheet.Name <> "Summary" Then
        ColNum = ColNum + 1

        NewSheet.Cells(1, ColNum).Formula _
    = "=HYPERLINK(""#""&CELL(""address"",'" & OldSheet.Name & "'!A1)," _
         & """" & OldSheet.Name & """)"


        NewSheet.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Value = OldSheet.Range("B11").Value
    End If
Next OldSheet

NewSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Note: Only the new results are shown in the chart.

This is the Summary worksheet after the code has run:
[Summary sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFsBU.png)

This is the Dashboard worksheet after the code has run:
[Dashboard Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrIlA.jpg)

Comment: If you add some example data and an example of the desired result you will probably get more people to look at this.

Comment: @dev1998 please check the attached image

Comment: Is that Pic the Summary sheet after the code has run?

Comment: Correct! And room A ,room B and room C are 3 different sheets.

Comment: OK, you are making progress. Do you now want the row with 3/1/2018 to go to a sheet called "charts"? What does that sheet look like?

Comment: True, Its an empty sheet now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want a non-VBA method, that once you've set it up you'll never have to mess with it?

We'll use some Names (aka Named Ranges) to reference the data.

I assume the sheet with the data you're plotting is "Summary".

Go to the Formulas tab, Define Name. In Name, enter `Labels`; for Scope, keep Workbook; in Refers To, enter `=Summary!$B$1:$E$1`. Click Enter.

Return to Define Name. In Name, enter `Name`; in Refers To, enter `=OFFSET(Summary!$A$1,COUNT(Summary!$A:$A),0)`. This returns the cell that is as many rows below A1 as there are values in column A.

Return one last time to Define Name. In Name, enter `Values`; in Refers To, enter `=OFFSET(Labels,COUNT(Summary!$A:$A),0)`. This returns the range which is as many rows below the `Labels` range we named above, as the number of values in column A.

Now select Summary!A1:D2 and insert a column chart on the Summary sheet. The chart shows the first date's values. Select the columns and look at the series formula. It should say this:

```
=SERIES(Summary!$A$2,Summary!$B$1:$D$1,Summary!$B$2:$D$2,1)
```

Edit this formula to read

```
=SERIES(Summary!Name,Summary!Labels,Summary!Values,1)
```

Excel accepts your changes. Since the scope of the Names was Workbook, Excel changes the series formula to this:

```
=SERIES(Book1.xlsm!Name,Book1.xlsm!Labels,Book1.xlsm!Values,1)
```

(or whatever your workbook's name is).

Comment: It will work fine if the dates are not previously written. In my case I need to generate today's date in the column bar (which is the last date with data). Note: All the date of 2018 are previously written in column A.

Comment: I've edited my code to add the date through vba, And your formulas are now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, see if this works for you:

```
Sub Worksheets_Summary()
    Dim OldSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim book As Workbook

    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim Range2 As Range
    Dim chartSheet As Worksheet


    Set book = ThisWorkbook
    Set NewSheet = book.Worksheets("Summary")
    RwNum = NewSheet.Columns(1).Find(Date).Row
    ColNum = 1
    For Each OldSheet In book.Worksheets
        If OldSheet.Name <> "Summary" Then
        ColNum = ColNum + 1

        NewSheet.Cells(1, ColNum).Formula _
         = "=HYPERLINK(""#""&CELL(""address"",'" & OldSheet.Name & "'!A1)," _
         & """" & OldSheet.Name & """)"


        NewSheet.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Value = OldSheet.Range("B11").Value
        End If
    Next OldSheet

    NewSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit


    Set chartSheet = book.Worksheets("charts")

    Set MyChart = chartSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered).Chart 'This is similar to the way I saw it done on the link I included.
        'You could use activesheet instead of chartsheet.

    Set Range1 = NewSheet.Range("A1:D1") ' Get Header from Summary Sheet
    Set Range2 = NewSheet.Range("A" & RwNum & ":D" & RwNum) ' Get most recent data row from Summary Sheet
    Set MyRange = Union(Range1, Range2)



    MyChart.SetSourceData source:=MyRange 'Use MyRange for the chart.

    MyChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("A" & 2).Value 'Get the date and use it as the chart title.


End Sub
```

I assumed you already had a sheet named "charts", so I didn't create one. I also assumed that only the most recent row from Sheet Summary is being copied to the charts sheet, and that existing data is over written.

I also assumed that the code you started with was already working to update the Summary sheet.

I used this to learn about creating charts with VBA: [https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/650547-create-column-chart-through-vba-automatically.html]

Comment: This code is for a specific case, it doesn't work for all cases. Range must increment in rows (each day + 1)

Comment: I think it would help a lot if you showed us what the "charts" sheet should look like, including a few rows that have incremented.

Comment: "charts" is empty. So, we shouldn't copy the rows. We must get the result from "Summary" sheet. If you edit your code to get the data from "summary" sheet (instead of copying the result to "charts" sheet and then get the data from this sheet), at this point we can use the value `RwNum`  to help us getting the latest result.

Comment: I'll take a look at doing that. In the meantime does the chart that is being created now look like what you want it to look like? If not please add a picture of what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: Done! Check the Dashboard image in the question.

Comment: OK, take a look at this.